# Symfony2: accessing parameter.yml in view ( php template )

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.5

am using following parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
    name: krishnakumar
```

but when an trying to access the parameter like the below

```
<?php echo $view->container->parameters['name']; ?>
```

this throwing an error

Error: Cannot access private property appProdDebugProjectContainer::$parameters

Comment: Why not get the parameter in your controller function, and then just pass it to the view?  This would offer more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<?php echo $view->container->getParameter('name'); ?>
```